# Rails AJAX (JSON) response reloads the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, web, reload

In the controller a response to an AJAX Request is following:

```
@response = {resp: "ack"}
render json: @response
```

JS which handles AJAX is:

```
$('#some_btn').click(function() {    

    var valuesToSubmit = $('#some_form').serialize();
    var url = $('#some_form').attr('action');

    console.log("VALUE: " + valuesToSubmit);
    console.log("URL: " + search_url);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url, //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

            console.log("saved");
            console.log(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

But the problem is that I don't get console messages, instead the page reloads and I get json as text on a new page. How to prevent this "non-true-AJAX" behaviour?

Comment: Try to use dataType: "json" instead of "JSON"

Comment: do you really trigger the ajax request?

Comment: Are you at least getting the first two console messages, before the $.ajax call? Based on your rails log, is it going to the controller and action that you expect? Have you checked the headers of the request and response using something like Firebug, and compared them to the headers used in working AJAX requests?

Comment: Try debugging the above javascript in firebug or any other browser equivalent by adding breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had almost the same problem. In my case, I was using the folliwing link to send the request:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to add_item_path(item), 
    class: 'ui icon button',
    id: "add-item-#{item.id}",
    method: :post do %>
      <%= fa_icon 'shopping-cart' %>
    <% end %>
 </td>
```

My js to send the ajax was:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:regex(id,add-item-[0-9]+)").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
        url: link,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('#notice-modal').modal('show');
        }
      });
    })
  });
```

and my rails controller action was:

```
  def add
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    current_cart << { item_id: @item.id, quantity: 1 }
    render json: {quantity: 1}
  end
```

So the problem was I using only `event.preventDefault()` but wasn't enought. For working fine, I need to use `event.stopPropagation()`. Like this:

```
  $("a:regex(id,add-item-[0-9]+)").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
      url: link,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#notice-modal').modal('show');
      }
    });
  })
```

The `event.stopPropagation()` is needed because rails component (rails-ujs I think) sent the request elsewhere. You can also remove the `method: :post`, and will work fine.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to prevent the default form submit action?

```
$('#some_btn').click(function(event) {  
  event.preventDefault();

  //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself.  Turns out, I'd just forgotten to add "//= require jquery_ujs" to my application.js file.  As soon as I added it, everything worked fine.